# can I stop users from executing binaries?

Tags: linux, sh

If I wish to create a binary executable, and I want to stop someone from executing it in my directory, but I still want them to be able to copy it to their own area, I have to give them read permissions, but not execute permission.

Now I realize that for files written in high-level languages, like python, execute permissions aren't really a concept. Anyone with read permission can simply run them using a command (python, for .py files, for instance), which is what's actually happening when someone "executes" them.

But binaries, I thought, were different.  They can be executed without read permission, because they really are being executed, not just shuffled off to an interpreter command which requires read permissions.

But then I learned about the sh command, which seems able to act on binaries (unlike bash, which refuses to).  Is there a way to disable this, or to shield a binary file from this?

Comment: What do you mean when you say that sh "seems able to act on binaries"? Can you give an example? If I type `sh /bin/rm`, for example, it reports a syntax error (because it's not a valid sh script).

Comment: The linker and loader still need to load a binary to execute it. No, +x without +r is not sufficient for execution.

Comment: ...and no, `sh` does not in any way circumvent this.

Comment: Perhaps you're thinking of _directories_, for which `+x` without `+r` is meaningful.

Comment: @KeithThompson Maybe I was confused.  I generated a file named a.out from a .cpp code, which then I would execute to get the code's output.  bash flat out refuses to act on binaries, but sh just gives syntax errors.  I thought maybe the file had been corrupted, and this was the cause of the syntax error. Now that I try, I can still execute it.

Comment: @anotherguy: Neither sh nor bash can *successfully* execute anything other than a valid shell script. bash does seem to check whether a file is binary before trying to execute it, but that's not particularly relevant. (Of course any shell can *invoke* a binary executable.)

Answer (score 1):

wat?

```
yac@rainbowdash % vim a.c
yac@rainbowdash % gcc a.c
yac@rainbowdash % ./a.out
a
yac@rainbowdash % ls -l a.out
-rwx------ 1 yac yac 11877 Oct 10 02:27 a.out*
yac@rainbowdash % chmod -x a.out
yac@rainbowdash % ./a.out
zsh: permission denied: ./a.out
yac@rainbowdash % sh ./a.out
./a.out: ./a.out: cannot execute binary file
yac@rainbowdash % cat a.c
#include <stdio.h>
void main(void) {printf("a\n");}
```

but if they can read it anyway, execution is just

```
yac@rainbowdash % cp a.out b.out
yac@rainbowdash % chmod +x b.out
yac@rainbowdash % ./b.out
a
```

a copy away

and if your concern is "execute in my directory" they can just

```
% cd your/directory && ./their/executable/copy
```

Comment: You'll also likely need to statically link it, otherwise you can just use the ELF dynamic linker/loader as you would with any other interpreted program. See man ld.so

Comment: Okay, but if they don't have write permission to my home directory, that last part won't work.  Are you saying they could cd to my home dir and then ./../their_home_dir/their_copy ?  I hadn't thought of that before, maybe it would have the same effect.

Comment: Yes they can. Read up on how linux processes work - fork/exec and inheriting env and stuff. So they can execute anything with CWD anywehere they can `cd` to but of course, if they don't have the write  permission there, they can't write there.